# i want to retrieve postgresql rds database credentials from aws lambda function through aws secrets manager using python

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

please provide me a program code for to retrieve postgres sql rds instance credentials from amazon lambda function through aws serets manager, please letme know how to update table in postgresql rds database instance through aws lambda sunction.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you saying that you _already_ have information in Secrets Manager and you simply wish to retrieve them from within an AWS Lambda function? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can open secrets manager and then open your secret, all the way down in the page you can see codes in different programming language which you can use in order to retrieve secrets from secret manager